# commandbutton executa método, porém estando valores nulos. Por que não está sendo atribuído os valores das inputstexts aos atributos da classe?

Tags: java, java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Em todos os exemplos que eu vi do código abaixo, o normal a ocorrer era, ao ser iniciada a página xhtml criar um novo objeto do tipo cliente. Através dos valores inseridos nos inputs setar os atributos desse objeto e o commandbutton poderia utilizar esses dados de alguma forma, invocando um método. Isso não está ocorrendo no código abaixo. Porque?

**Código JSF:**

```xml
 <p:panel id="dados-cliente" header="Dados do Cliente">
      <h:form>
           <p:panelGrid id="dados-cliente-container" columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="CNPJ:"/>
                <p:inputMask mask="##.###.###/####-##" value="# {clienteMB.cliente.cnpj}"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Razão Social:"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{clienteMB.cliente.razao_social}"/>
                <p:commandButton action="#{clienteMB.Salvar}" value="Salvar" process="@this"/>
           </p:panelGrid>
      </h:form>
  </p:panel>
```

**Código Java:**

```
@ManagedBean
public class ClienteMB {
    Cliente cliente;

    public ClienteMB(){
        cliente = new Cliente();
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public void Salvar(){
        System.out.println(cliente.getRazao_social());
        System.out.println(cliente.getCnpj());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que seu `<p:button>` está com o atributo `process="@this"`. Isso significa que na requisição AJAX que é feita, apenas ele é processado.

Para que os demais `inputs` do seu formulário sejam processados e os valores atribuídos ao `Bean` você precisa alterar o atributo `process` para `process="@form"` ou sendo mais restritivo `process="dados-cliente-container"`.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, deu certinho aqui agora! Você é o cara!